# How to not capture a group in regex if it is followed by an another group

Tags: python, regex

If I have a string eg.: 'hcto,231' or 'hcto.12' I want to be able to capture 'o,231' or 'o.12' and process it as a number ('hct' is random and any other string can replace it).
But I don't want to capture if the 'o' character if followed by a decimal number eg: 'wordo.23.12' or 'wordo,23,12'.

I've tried using the following regex:

`([oO][.,][0-9]+)(?!([.,][0-9]+))`

but it always matches.
In the string 'hct**o.2**2.23' it matches the bold part, but I don't want it to match anything. Is there a way to combine groups so it won't match if the negative lookahead is true.

Comment: Add word boundary, `([oO][.,][0-9]+)\b(?!([.,][0-9]+))` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/HFROWU/1)). Or, add `\d` alternative to the lookahead, `[oO][.,]\d+(?![.,]?\d)` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/HFROWU/3))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The match occurs in `hcto.22.23` because the lookahead triggers backtracking, and since `[0-9]+` match match a single `2` (it does not have to match `22`) the match succeeds and returns a smaller, [unexpected match](https://regex101.com/r/d7cUrH/1):

[image]

It seems the simplest way to fix the current issue is to make the dot or comma pattern in the lookahead optional, and remove unnecessary groups:

```py
[oO][.,]\d+(?![.,]?\d)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/HFROWU/3).

**Details**

- `[oO]` - `o` or `O`
- `[.,]` - a dot or comma
- `\d+` - one or more digits
- `(?![.,]?\d)` - not followed with `.`/`,` and a digit, or just with a digit.